# Emacs mode: how to specify that thing in square brackets should be colored

Tags: emacs, elisp, mode

I write a simple emacs mode. How do I explicitly specify that all things in e.g. square brackets should be colored. Must be smth like that:

```
( (if thing is in square brackets) . font-lock-string-face)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're writing a major mode, but `font-lock-add-keywords` works also in minor
modes. Check out its documentation with `C-h f RET font-lock-add-keywords`.

```
(define-derived-mode my-mode text-mode "mymode"
  ;; some init code
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\[\\(.*\\)\\]"
                                 1 font-lock-warning-face prepend)))
  ;; some more init code
)
```

Answer (score 3):

So here's a summary:
To add new keywords to a mode

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'emacs-lisp-mode
  '(("foo" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

It can have regexps:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'emacs-lisp-mode '(("\\[\\(.+?\\)\\]" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

(this makes font of everything in square brackets to be of a given color)

For the current mode and current emacs session – you can just evaluate the following:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\[\\(.+?\\)\\]" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

(note - You don't specify a mode here)

To make it permanent You can add it as a hook to the mode:

```
(add-hook 'bk-grmx-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\[\\(.+?\\)\\]" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
          )
)
```

You can also add it to a mode specification:

```
(define-derived-mode bk-grmx-mode fundamental-mode
  (setq font-lock-defaults '(bk-grmx-keyWords))
  ;; the next line is added:
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\[\\(.+?\\)\\]" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
  (setq mode-name "bk-grmx-mode")
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd either have to extend the mode you're in to incorporate a new syntax rule or you can simply use `highlight-regexp` for quick and dirty highlighting.

Comment: To extend the mode - that's what I want. The mode I'm going to extend is a simple one - also written by me (it has tab-completion, syntax highlighting and smart comments through dwim). `hightlight-regexp` surely will work. Thanks for Your answer.

Comment: I've extended the basic markdown mode [here](https://github.com/nibrahim/Hyde/blob/master/hyde-md.el). You can look at that for how. It doesn't do any syntax highlighting but you can probably get that by adding to the `font-lock-defaults` variable in your mode.

Comment: BTW: how do I specify a color? This doesn't specify it: `(highlight-regexp "\\[\\(.+?\\)\\]" 'hi-red)`

Comment: It will use a `face` which you have to `customize`.

Comment: Well - yes. But how do I specify with a command: `(highlight-regexp REGEXP &optional FACE)`? Because I write a mode...

Comment: If you're writing a mode, don't use highlight-regexp. Use a font-lock-rule.